# Identify the current character being read in "read" method of fileinputstream?

Tags: java

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("filetoreadfrom.txt");

while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {

Integer cobj = new Integer(c);
System.out.println("The Current data being read is :" + cobj.byteValue());
out.write(c);
}
```

The sysouts give an intvalue representing the byte being read.But i want to print  the exact character being read.Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you must see a "tick mark below the votes which is disabled now.. as you hover over with your mouse, you should see an instruction to "click that to accept answers".. click on that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the type conversion `(char) cobj.byteValue()`

Comment: i liked your answer.But how to accept answers in stackoverflow

Answer (score 9):

In `InputStream` contains *bytes*, not *characters*. What does it even mean to talk about the "character" when you're in the middle of an mp3 file for example?

If you want to read text data, you need a `Reader`, e.g. an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around an `InputStream` with a specific encoding.

Comment: @Rekha: You click on the tick next to whichever answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `BufferedReader and InputStreamReader` but you can also use such code:

`BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

  int len;

  while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {

      String line = new String(buffer, 0, len);`